# Access to resources folder in a Spring / Maven application

Tags: java, spring, jsp, maven, spring-mvc

In my Spring application, developed with Maven, my resources files (css and js files from boostrap and jquery) are all stores in the folder src/main/resources. In my views (jsp files, stored in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp) I make reference this files this way:

```
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/extras/css/signin.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">
```

which don't work, because when I open the page, the browser can't download this files from server (a error 404 is triggered).

What the right form to link to this files in my jsp files?

ps.: In my configuration classes, I have this settings for my resources files:

**WebConfig.java**

```
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(value="spring.example")
@Configuration
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/jquery-ui/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/jquery-ui/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/bootstrap/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/bootstrap/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/extras/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/extras/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

}
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(value="spring.example")
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService usuario;

    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(usuario)
            .passwordEncoder(encoder());
    }

    private Md5PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new Md5PasswordEncoder();
    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/acesso/erro").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/resources/bootstrap/**", "/resources/jquery-ui/**", "/resources/extras/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/acesso/login").permitAll()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login").permitAll()
                .usernameParameter("login")
                .passwordParameter("senha")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/acesso/start")
                .failureUrl("/acesso/login")
                .and()
            .rememberMe()
                .key("lembrete")
                .useSecureCookie(true)
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/acesso/login").permitAll();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store JS/CSS files   in `webapp` folder of your app. Maven's `src/main/resources` folder is only for resources that will not accessible from client (this resources usually consumed by Java app, not by client browser). So just move your files to `webapp` folder and reference to them from JSP